# Installing OpenAI Gym enviorments from github

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-gym

Can someone kindly explain to me step by step how to install a gym environment from github? I tried some things but I didn't understand what they were doing and they didn't work. for Exp:

```
py -3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/grantsrb/Gym-Snake
py -3 -m pip install -e .[dev]
```

these are the enviorments in question:

https://github.com/grantsrb/Gym-Snake

https://github.com/nicomon24/Sneks

When I run the following code:

```
import gym
env=gym.make('snake-v0')
```

This is the error message shown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 118, in spec
    return self.env_specs[id]
KeyError: 'snake-v0'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\snaketry.py", line 21, in <module>
    env=gym.make('snake-v0')
  File "C:\Users\Aj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 142, in make
    return registry.make(id, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Aj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 86, in make
    spec = self.spec(path)
  File "C:\Users\Aj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py", line 128, in spec
    raise error.UnregisteredEnv('No registered env with id: {}'.format(id))
gym.error.UnregisteredEnv: No registered env with id: snake-v0
```

Comment: _when I try to make a new environment currently there is an error message saying "No registered env with id: snake-v0"_ Which command(s) produce that error? Please share the entire error output.

Comment: Edited to include full output